# How to use Tab to autocomplete

Tags: vb.net

i have a Textbox in vb.net and have assigned to it autocomplete data , when i enter the first letter of the word it shows a suggestions but when i choose one and click tab to complete the word it goes to next text box

**for example :**
i have put these suggestion as a source for the textbox
GigabitEthernet

but i want to complete it with a number , so i have to click tab and complete

i have tried all types of auto complete with no luck

is it doable to complete the word when i click in tab without going to the next box?

Comment: I haven't tested but I would think that you would hit Enter to select without navigating.

Comment: Do you have code to help understand your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then e.IsInputKey = True
End Sub
```

Comment: it's blocked the TAB , it didn't complete the word

Comment: It works fine with me , my settings `.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend` and  `.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.FileSystemDirectories`

Comment: Thank you , i have missed something from the code that you have mentioned , it's working fine now